# Strange SQL query generated by EntityFramework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

Here is my SQL query which is generated by EF.

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1884) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Opened connection at 26-Mar-14 23:39:33 +01:00
Opened connection at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
Started transaction at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
Started transaction at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
INSERT [dbo].[Tagger]([tagCount], [imageId], [tag])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [id]
FROM [dbo].[Tagger]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [id] = scope_identity()
-- @0: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- @2: 'tag1' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- Executing at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
INSERT [dbo].[Tagger]([tagCount], [imageId], [tag])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SELECT [id]
FROM [dbo].[Tagger]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [id] = scope_identity()
-- @0: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Completed in 3 ms with result: SqlDataReader

-- @2: 'tag1' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- Executing at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
-- Completed in 0 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Committed transaction at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
Committed transaction at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
Closed connection at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
Closed connection at 26-Mar-14 23:39:35 +01:00
```

I think that it is strange, because my code in controller seems like this

```
private void addTagsToTagger(FormCollection form)
{

    char[] delimiter = { ',' };
    List<string> userTags = form["tags"].Split(delimiter).ToList();


    using (var ctx = new vestibulyContext())
    {
        ctx.Database.Log = s => log(s);
        foreach (var tagItem in userTags)
        {
            if (!IssetTagInDb(ctx, tagItem))
            {
                var item = tagItem.ToLower().Trim();
                var t = new Tagger() { imageId = Int16.Parse(form["imgId"]), tag = item, tagCount = 1 };
                ctx.Tagger.Add(t);
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }

}

private bool IssetTagInDb(vestibulyContext ctx, string tag)
{
    tag = tag.ToLower().Trim();
    return ctx.Tagger.Any(t => t.tag == tag); 
}
```

So, in every step in foreach loop I call SaveChanges() method and I don´t know why does EF generate query like this. At the beginning are 2 lines Opened connection. Why? After that 2 times Started transaction and after that 2 times INSERT query. Is it normal behavior? I can´t imagine why is there 2 times insert query when I used 1 times Add() method and after 1 times SaveChanges() method in every step. Therefore my records are 2 times added into database. Any idea what is the problem with that?Thanks.

Comment: Have you used break points to verify that userTags only has 1 item in it? And that addTagsToTagger is only being called once?

Comment: userTags contains only unique items and addTagsToTagger is called only once.